# While Loop Unidentified Index

Tags: php

php 7

I have a section in a php script which gathers info from a database. I am not the original author and am fairly new to php.
The table in the database goes up to "doc16" however when testing this script I get an error for the following code because "Unidentified index: doc17".

Here is the section giving the error:

```
$sql="select * from users where username='$userid'";
$result=mysqli_query($info,$sql);
$line1=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$docname="doc1";
$ptr=1;
while($permission=($line1["$docname"])){
   $inquirytable[$ptr]=$permission;
   $ptr++;
   $docname="doc".$ptr;

}
```

`$info` is the database connection info

In the database the `doc#X` for 1-16 is either a yes or no value
I have tried playing with the values of $ptr to to force it to make `$docname` = `doc16` or `doc2` but no matter the value that just causes a `Fatal : Allowed memory size` error.

Any direction or assistance is appreciated. I will do my best to provide more information if necessary.

**EDIT 1:**
using `var_dump ($line1["$docname"]);` before my while loop returns
`string 'Y' (length=1)`

Comment: Please secure your requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496.

Comment: @Blackhole definitely planning to make the the site more secure, thank you

Comment: Check to make sure that `$line1[$docname]` exists before you try to assign the permission

Comment: @u_mulder the number of possible `doc.$ptr` is larger in some instances

Comment: @aynber a `var_dump()` of `$line1["$docname"]` before the while loop returns `string 'Y' (length=1)` so it seems to exist

Comment: It's not breaking before the while loop, it's breaking in the middle. You overwrite `$docname` at the end of the loop. You hit 16, and at the end of the loop, `$docname` becomes `doc17`. Then it goes back to the loop, and does `$permission = ($line1['doc17'])`. However, $line1 does not have the index `doc17`, so it breaks.

Comment: Instead of a while loop and renaming the columns, you might be better off doing `foreach($line1 as $docname => $permission)`. And then inside the loop, only do the assignment if `strpos($docname, 'doc') === 0`